# Push notification Chrome Mobile Ver 42+

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, push-notification, chrome-gcm

I am trying a demo of push notification suggested by this article.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web?hl=en

and trying to run code from github https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/push-messaging-and-notifications

As per instruction I have done following things -
1. Created project on google developer console.
2. Added browser application key in to config.js > gcmAPIKey :'browser api key' 
3.Added gsm_sender_id :'Project number' into manifest.json 
4. Hosted application on https://somedomain.com
and result is this [image]

Whenever I click on SendPushMessage button it doesn't show any notification. While debugging, I found that this request get fired 
`https://xxsomedomainxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/get/?subscriptionId=APA91bE_xyl2sP8l1pa8j4n84VGfJgKVb28I0DJK5qo9zUVLy0ZSRsyl2BbjLDSZ-Y625LqsmMp3rIH4PW3s1v_ccBOdCbWYsxaF525FHRbx5odr-z1a1uPrP4zqy4DFlKkwa9pyHhkdxL0ggxGBbC_bB6LTZSDuTKlDeXTRhywcY9X5KxBXrxhS_4M8oJFUi3eW6FikEUiJ` 

As per my observation I need to catch **substriptionId** on server and need to do something with it. So what kind of code should I need to write on server for below API

> https://xxsomedomainxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/get/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created one WCF REST service with following code and its sending notification to android chrome 42+. 
But one problem is here, notification shows message from service-worker.js file, not from in this code

> var value = "Hello from server";

. I am working on it and update this answer soon.

> Please update this function in main.js file

```
function getNotification(subscription) {

    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (serviceWorkerRegistration) {
        serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe()
          .then(function (subscription) {
              console.log('getNotification', subscription)
              fetch('/pushnotificationservice.svc/sendnotification?key=' + subscription.subscriptionId).then(function (obj) {
                  console.log('getNotification', obj)
              });
          });
    });
```

> WCF Service Code

```
public string SendNotification(string key)
        {
             ServiceData myServiceData = new ServiceData();
            try
            {
                string GoogleAppID = "2440XXXXXXXX";//put your project number here
                string redId = key;
                var SENDER_ID = "youremail@gmail.com";//I haven't tried with another junk value
                var value = "Hello from server";//this message do not displayed in notification
                WebRequest tRequest;
                tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
                tRequest.Method = "post";
                tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";

                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "Your browser key"));

                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

                string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + key + "";
                Console.WriteLine(postData);
                Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();

                WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

                dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

                tReader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                tResponse.Close();
                return sResponseFromServer;
            }
            catch (FaultException fex)
            {
                myServiceData.Result = false;
                myServiceData.ErrorMessage = "unforeseen error occurred. Please try later.";
                myServiceData.ErrorDetails = fex.ToString();
                throw new FaultException<ServiceData>(myServiceData);
            }
        }
```